# e.preventDefault not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I'm building a site in Magento 2 and on mobile the first two levels of the navigation do not navigate to there pages but rather just act as click targets to open there respective sub menus.

My code is structured roughly as follows

```
 <ul id="ui-id-1" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="menu" tabindex="0">

    <li class="level0 nav-3 has-active last level-top parent ui-menu-item open" role="presentation">

      <a href="http://site.dev/shop.html" class="level-top ui-corner-all ui-state-active" aria haspopup="true" id="ui-id-4" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
        <span>Shop</span>
      </a>

      <ul class="level0 submenu ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="menu" aria-expanded="true" style="display: block; position: relative; top: 90px; left: 0px;">

        <li class="level1 nav-3-3 parent ui-menu-item" role="presentation">

          <a href="http://site.dev/shop/accessories.html" aria-haspopup="true" id="ui-id-7" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
            <span>Accessories</span>
          </a>

          <ul class="level1 submenu ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all expanded" role="menu" aria-hidden="true" aria-expanded="false" style="display: none;">
            //submenu code removed for brevity
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

As you can see in the code below both the .level-top li and the .level1 li have jQuery click events that should stop the a from being followed and open the sub menu. they both open the submenu but the .level1 click event doesn't disabled the a link and its subsequently followed.

```
    $(document).on('click', '.page-header li.level-top.parent>a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).parents('li.level-top').hasClass('open')){
            $('li.level-top').removeClass('open');
        }else{
            $('li.level-top').removeClass('open');
            $(this).parents('li.level-top').addClass('open');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.page-header li.level1.parent>a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        if($(this).parents('li.level1').hasClass('open')){
            $('li.level1').removeClass('open');
        }else{
            $('li.level1').removeClass('open');
            $(this).parents('li.level1').addClass('open');
        }
        return false;
    });
```

I've tried everything and this is driving me nuts. any ideas?

Comment: It doesnt follow through for me when I remove .page-header from the click path, see: https://jsfiddle.net/khdpd258/1 And you could possibly simplify your javascript instead of doing similar functionality over and over again, by targeting '.parent > a' and finding common ground for opening closing sections.

Comment: I don't know if this makes a difference, but your > selector should be space-padded like so: 'li.level-top.parent > a'

Comment: No that wouldn't matter. That's just formatting for better readability. but there is a space missing inside your level1 li before aria-haspopup="true"

Comment: I edited the code slightly for brevity so any html mistakes were probably from that